# What's the best classification method for capturing packets in heavy traffic

Tags: java, classification, data-storage, packet-capture, jpcap

I want to capture packets from a crowded network and classify it by user request. I use *java* and *jpcap* for capturing packets. now I'm using array threads for each req packet. it's realy slow and there is many conflicts among threads. **what's the best data structure for this purpose?**

after that, I'm saving packets (req/response) into a file, that is very slow for such a heavy work. **what should I do for saving my datas?**

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll need some example code to help you with the first part, because your question is a little vague. `what's the best data structure for this purpose?` could be anything depending on what exactly you need that structure for.

The `JpcapWriter` is pretty fast. I need to capture roughly 330mb of raw packet data from a 2 minutes of capture, and I haven't had a problem with being able to write it to disk while continuing to capture.